# ASP.NET is ScaffoldColumn(false) and ReadOnly(true) enough to stop overposting attacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC 5, if we use `ScaffoldColumn` set to false, and `ReadOnly` set to true, would that be enough to completely stop Overposting attacks? For example if we create the following inside a model:

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
[ReadOnly(true)]
public virtual string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

And then used the default scaffolding generator for a CRUD view/controller.

Would that automatically generated view and controller `MyProperty` be completely isolated from Overposting attacks, and really any kind of user interaction?

Comment: Use view models and include only those properties you need to edit and map to your data models.

Comment: That's a valid solution. But in the scenario I'm working on only one field needs to get excluded. I think building a view model with all the other fields except for one might be ultimately needless if this approach covers what I need to do.